# How to join data frames with multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

This is my first data.

```
# A tibble: 10 x 6
   start_location_Long start_location_Lat end_location_Long end_location_Lat length clusterNum
                 <dbl>              <dbl>             <dbl>            <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>
 1                101.               13.8              101.             13.8  1363.          1
 2                101.               13.8              101.             13.8  1224.          1
 3                101.               13.8              101.             13.8  1045.          1
 4                101.               13.8              101.             13.8   106.          1
 5                101.               13.8              101.             13.8  5037.          1
 6                101.               13.8              101.             13.8  3682.          2
 7                101.               13.8              101.             13.8   866.          2
 8                101.               13.8              101.             13.8  1764.          6
 9                101.               13.8              101.             13.8  1950.          6
10                101.               13.8              101.             13.8   931.          6
```

```
df1 <- structure(list(start_location_Long = c(100.56348, 100.54894,100.56529, 100.54631, 100.57274, 100.54883, 100.53564, 100.55054,100.55533, 100.55743), start_location_Lat = c(13.79793, 13.81345,13.75772, 13.81105, 13.77156, 13.8129, 13.80799, 13.79688, 13.78796,13.76681), end_location_Long = c(100.56723, 100.55415, 100.56994,100.54612, 100.56129, 100.53425, 100.53375, 100.54621, 100.57325,100.5611), end_location_Lat = c(13.80969, 13.80363, 13.766, 13.81199,13.81569, 13.78282, 13.80038, 13.81225, 13.78991, 13.77442),length = c(1362.81284624, 1223.81637204, 1045.02327624, 106.008861913,5036.9607016, 3682.49608165, 866.396979262, 1763.77103489,1949.69621816, 930.799744269), clusterNum = c(1, 1, 1, 1,1, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(clusterNum = c(1, 2, 6), .rows = structure(list(1:5, 6:7,8:10), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of","vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = c("tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df","tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And this is the second data that I would join.

```
# A tibble: 10 x 12
   start_location_~ start_location_~ seg_2_lat seg_2_lon seg_3_lat seg_3_lon seg_4_lat seg_4_lon seg_5_lat seg_5_lon end_location_Lat
              <dbl>            <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>            <dbl>
 1             13.8             101.      13.7      101.      13.6      101.      13.7      101.      13.7      101.             13.8
 2             13.7             101.      13.7      101.      13.7      101.      13.7      101.      13.7      101.             13.7
 3             13.6             101.      13.6      101.      13.6      101.      13.6      101.      13.6      101.             13.6
 4             13.6             101.      13.6      101.      13.6      101.      13.6      101.      13.6      101.             13.6
 5             13.6             101.      13.6      101.      13.6      101.      13.6      101.      13.6      101.             13.6
 6             13.6             101.      13.6      101.      13.6      101.      13.6      101.      13.6      101.             13.6
 7             13.6             101.      13.6      101.      13.6      101.      13.6      101.      13.6      101.             13.6
 8             13.9             101.      13.9      101.      13.9      101.      13.9      101.      13.9      101.             13.9
 9             13.9             101.      13.9      101.      13.9      101.      13.9      101.      13.9      101.             13.9
10             13.9             101.      13.9      101.      13.9      101.      13.9      101.      13.9      101.             13.9
# ... with 1 more variable: end_location_Long <dbl>
```

```
df2 <- structure(list(start_location_Lat = c(13.79793, 13.66859, 13.63345,13.60629, 13.56958, 13.60148, 13.60283, 13.93821, 13.92455, 13.88824), start_location_Long = c(100.56348, 100.72032, 100.71102, 100.69999,100.78749, 100.71103, 100.70543, 100.51485, 100.59617, 100.60413), seg_2_lat = c(13.65382, 13.66353, 13.63349, 13.61857, 13.57759,13.60519, 13.60118, 13.92443, 13.94145, 13.89331), seg_2_lon = c(100.67562,100.71894, 100.71096, 100.70363, 100.78828, 100.7129, 100.71196,100.52361, 100.61323, 100.60713), seg_3_lat = c(13.63679, 13.66353,13.63349, 13.6344, 13.58393, 13.61076, 13.60193, 13.92633, 13.93945,13.88969), seg_3_lon = c(100.71057, 100.71894, 100.71096, 100.71093,100.79077, 100.71317, 100.71915, 100.52603, 100.64207, 100.60779), seg_4_lat = c(13.65828, 13.66353, 13.63349, 13.6344, 13.58385,13.62504, 13.60487, 13.93948, 13.93277, 13.88969), seg_4_lon = c(100.71631,100.71894, 100.71096, 100.71093, 100.79403, 100.71832, 100.71483,100.54145, 100.68214, 100.60779), seg_5_lat = c(13.65828, 13.65958,13.63349, 13.6344, 13.59328, 13.63082, 13.605, 13.93382, 13.93277,13.88728), seg_5_lon = c(100.71631, 100.71773, 100.71096, 100.71093,100.76465, 100.71459, 100.71402, 100.56506, 100.68214, 100.61401), end_location_Lat = c(13.80969, 13.65258, 13.63349, 13.63433,13.59612, 13.63241, 13.60567, 13.92856, 13.92057, 13.88462),end_location_Long = c(100.56723, 100.71571, 100.71096, 100.71101,100.74922, 100.71297, 100.71292, 100.58192, 100.68588, 100.62013)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

In df1 and df2 have the same values in 4 columns which are `start_location_Long` `start_location_Lat` `end_location_Long` and `end_location_Lat`. So, I want to merge the df1 and df2 together and my output will be df1 come up with extra columns from df2 (Left outer join?).

my expected result would have columns like;

| start_location_Long | start_location_Lat | end_location_Long | end_location_Lat | length | clusterNum | seg_2_lat | seg_2_lon | seg_3_lat | seg_3_lon | seg_4_lat | seg_4_lon | seg_5_lat | seg_5_lon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Thank you in advance for any helps.

Comment: You may want to check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(dplyr)
df_out <- left_join(df1, df2, by = c("start_location_Long","start_location_Lat", "end_location_Long", "end_location_Lat"))
```